# NaNs not recognized in df.loc or for loops

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

I currently have a df with a column `Outliers`. When I do:

```
df.Outliers.value_counts(dropna = False)
```

I get:

```
NaN    2862
1.0     600
0.0     257
```

However, when I try to display only these rows with:

```
df.loc[df.Outliers == np.nan] # numpy was imported as np
```

I get an output of 0 rows. Why are the NaN rows not being recognized as NaN? I have verified that these NaN values are of the type `numpy.float64`, so they aren't strings that need to be converted. Why are they not recognized as NaNs sometimes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas needs help sometimes when working with `np.nan` as it isn't always recognized correctly. However, you can use a `isna()` to find all columns/rows where there is data that includes a nan

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column1' : [np.nan, 2, 3, 4],
    'Column2' : [1, np.nan, 3, np.nan]
})
df.loc[df['Column1'].isna()]
```

Comment: ah gotcha. Thank you! I am trying to use this in a for loop, but when I try to put in an ```elif row.isna():``` I get a ```'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'isna'```. I also tried doing ```elif row is None```, but that didn't identify the NaNs either.

Comment: I see you marked my answer as "answered," but I see you had a question. Were you able to figure it out or did you have more questions?

Comment: row.isna() doesn't seem to work on single cells, which was my question - how can I index a specific cell as NA or not NA?